# Using associative arrays to display records from mysql into table dynamically

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table, associative-array

I'm trying to build a table like so dynamically from query

Here is a query

> SELECT MONTH(c.pat_added_date) AS month, COUNT(a.ana_id) as total,
> YEAR(c.pat_added_date) AS year FROM lab_patient_analysis AS b
>
> ```
>                       LEFT JOIN lab_analysis AS a
>                       ON a.ana_id = b.ana_id
>
>                       LEFT JOIN lab_patients AS c
>                       ON c.pat_id = b.pat_id
>
>                       WHERE 
>                       a.ana_id = '3' AND 
>                       YEAR(c.pat_added_date) BETWEEN '2012' AND '2013'
>                       GROUP BY MONTH(c.pat_added_date)
>                       ORDER BY YEAR(c.pat_added_date), MONTH(c.pat_added_date)
> ```

and here is what query returns

```
month | total | year
1         13     2012
7         9      2012
8         33     2012
3         21     2013
6         8      2013
....
```

here is a php function I've used for arrays

```
function array_set(&$a, $path, $value) {
    if(!is_array($path))
        $path = explode($path[0], substr($path, 1));
    $key = array_pop($path);
    foreach($path as $k) {
        if(!isset($a[$k]))
            $a[$k] = array();
        $a = &$a[$k];
    }
    $a[$key ? $key : count($a)] = $value;
}
```

and the point where I'm stuck

```
$yr = null;
while($row ... ))
{
 if($yr != $row['year']) {
   $yr = $row['year'];
   array_set($array, array($row['year'], $row['month']), $row['total']);
   echo '</tr></tr>';
   echo '<th scope="row">'.$row['year'].'</th>';
 }
  
 echo '<td>'.$row['total'];
}
```

arrays returned

```
Array
(
    [2012] => Array
        (
            [1] => 13
            [7] => 9
            [8] => 33
        )

    [2013] => Array
        (
            [3] => 21
            [6] => 8
        )

)
```

And I would like to produce the following table

```
        Jan| Feb| Mar | Apr | May | Jun | Jul | Sep | Oct | Nov | Dec
  2012   13   0    0     0     0     0     9    33     0     0     0
  2013   0    0    21    0     0     8     0     0     0     0     0
```

Hope that makes sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to get this out of it:

```
<?php

// Build source array.. You should already have this layout by the looks of it.

$array = array('2012' => array("1" => 13, "7" => 9, "8" => 33),
                '2013' => array("3" => 21, "6" => 8));

// Loop over every year.

foreach ($array as $year => $values) {

        for ($i = 1; $i <= 12; $i++) { // Loop through months 1 .. 12

                if (!$values[$i]) { // If there is no value for this month, pad it with 0 (Note string "0", else it leaves it empty)
                        $array[$year][$i] = "0";
                }
        }

        // Sort it out, probably won't need this actually, but it doesn't hurt to have it.
        ksort($array[$year], SORT_NATURAL);
}

// Print out the array 
var_dump($array);
```

I get this output:

```
array(2) {
  [2012]=>
  array(12) {
    [1]=>
    int(13)
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [6]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [7]=>
    int(9)
    [8]=>
    int(33)
    [9]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [10]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [11]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [12]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  [2013]=>
  array(12) {
    [1]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [2]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [3]=>
    int(21)
    [4]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [5]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [6]=>
    int(8)
    [7]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [8]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [9]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [10]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [11]=>
    string(1) "0"
    [12]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Will test it later and see if this produces what I want, thanks for your efforts

Comment: Thanks, it works just the way that I wanted but can't manage to get rid of "offset" errors, any idea?
I'll accept that answer as an accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way I would do it :

1. Create the array and fill it with zeros (in your example it would be a 2*12 array)
2. Query database
3. Walk query results and fill them into your array ($myarray[$data['month']][$data['$year']] = data['total'])
4. Display table with the values in your array

Comment: The array is generated and filled dynamically based on the query return results, so creating and array manually and fillinng it with zeros is useless

Comment: Yes, it's filled with the results from the query but if a month has no results that element is not set. The purpose of filling the array with zeros is to avoid testing each element with `isset()` before using it in your table.